# Rewrite URL for Nginx (.htccess)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, nginx, url-rewriting

I have a domain:  `domain.com/`

I have an embedded player:

```
domain.com/youtube/video/
```

so when I put a link like this:

```
domain.com/youtube/video/?vidid=YoutubeID
```

on my first folder domain `domain.com/youtube`is a list with my videos. If I click on one, it goes to the embedded player using `request_URI` videoid.. so this works.

Now I want a rewrite rule for nginx...  or the right `.htaccess` would work so I can convert it.

The rule should remove the `?videoid=`  part from `domain.com/youtube/video/YoutubeID` so that I do not have to type videoid= everytime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it sounds like you want to rewrite the URL from `/youtube/video/?vidid=YoutubeID` to `/youtube/video/YoutubeID`

```
# rewrite from `/youtube/video/?vidid=YoutubeID` 
#           to `/youtube/video/YoutubeID`
location = /youtube/video/ {
    return 302 $uri$arg_vidid;
}
```

Alternatively, it seems like you want to provide an `a href` for the same:

```
# provide a page with a[href] that'll remove "?vidid="
location = /youtube/video/ {
    return 200 "<!doctype html><title>$uri$arg_vidid</title><p><a href='$uri$arg_vidid'>$uri$arg_vidid</a></p>"
}
```